# Type inference with 'as const'

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript function returning a specific typed object like this.

```
type ImageFormat = {
  type: 'image/avif' | 'image/jpeg' | 'image/png' | 'image/svg+xml' | 'image/webp';
};

const sampleFunction = (): { format: ImageFormat } => {
  const format: ImageFormat = {
    type: 'image/png',
  };

  return {
    format,
  };
};
```

It works fine, but when it returns an object merged with another, it needs `as const` to specify the type:

```
type ImageFormat = {
  type: 'image/avif' | 'image/jpeg' | 'image/png' | 'image/svg+xml' | 'image/webp';
};

const sampleFunction = (): { format: ImageFormat } => {
  const typedFormat: ImageFormat = {
    type: 'image/png',
  };

  const format = {
    ...typedFormat,
    type: 'image/png' as const, <-- An error occurs without "as const"
  };

  return {
    format,
  };
};
```

Error:

```
Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ImageFormat'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"image/avif" | "image/jpeg" | "image/png" | "image/svg+xml" | "image/webp"'.ts(2322)
type.ts(5, 30): The expected type comes from property 'format' which is declared here on type '{ format: ImageFormat; }'
```

Why?

Comment: The newly generated `format` constant is just a plain object without any specific type information. This is exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: If you set again format:ImageFormat in the second case you can remove as const, because as the comment above says

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `const format = { type: 'image/png' }` is inferred as `{ type: string; }` per default and `type: string` is not specific enough to be assignable to the `type` [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `ImageFormat`.

A [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) helps here because it forces TypeScript to infer the narrowest possible type which will be the literal string `'image/png'`. That way `{ format }` is assignable to the functions return type.

Arguably it's *better* to just assert to `ImageFormat` since the literal type information you get with `as const` will be lost anyway after returning from the function:

```
const format = {
   ...typedFormat,
   type: 'image/png' as ImageFormat["type"]
};
```

Comment: Would you elaborate this?
>Arguably it's better to just assert to ImageFormat since the literal type information you get with as const will be lost anyway after returning from the function:

Comment: `sampleFunction` is annotated with a return type of `{ format: ImageFormat }`. So, at the end of the function implementation we will eventually have to return that type. In order to return `format` we need to type it in such a way that it is assignable to the function's return type (That was the initial problem). One way to achieve that type compatibility is by using a const assertion. The literal type TypeScript infers with `as const` IS assignable to `ImageFormat["type"] because it is a subtype of it.

Comment: My point is that it might be better to just directly assert to `ImageFormat["type"]` because when calling the function it always returns a value of type `ImageFormat["type"]` and never the literal string inferred by `as const`. Thus we can directly assert to the type we actually need and not to something more specific which isn't necessary anyway. However, both ways compile properly and IMO in that specific situation it's fine to use both ways which is why I said "Arguably" and put *better* in italic.

Comment: Well noted. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The `type` property in `ImageFormat` is limited to a specific set of strings. In order to ensure that the object is adhering to this type, TypeScript wants you to use `as const` since it sets the property to read-only. Thereby, you won't be able to change the type and break the type with an unsupported value (e.g. `image/mp3`) after object creation.

This is also known as *const assertion*, and makes the string be treated as a literal type instead of just a string.

Comment: See Behemoth's better answer for links and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

On top of [what Behemoth just said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77306728/3745332), I suggest another way to mitigate this issue. If you use TypeScript 4.9 or above, there is a `satisfies` keyword available which may help you.

Basically because you have string literal types in your `ImageFormat` when you write `{ type: ... } satisfies ImageFormat`, `type` value will be compared against all available type values in `ImageFormat['type']` and will be casted to the exact value from the union if there is a match, otherwise throws you an type error (e.g. `Type '"image/png3"' is not assignable to type '"image/avif" | "image/jpeg" | "image/png" | "image/svg+xml" | "image/webp"'. Did you mean '"image/png"'?`)

You can update your code the following way to make it work without `as const` if you wish:

```js
type ImageFormat = {
  type: 'image/avif' | 'image/jpeg' | 'image/png' | 'image/svg+xml' | 'image/webp';
};

const sampleFunction = (): { format: ImageFormat } => {
  const typedFormat = {
    type: 'image/png',
  } satisfies ImageFormat;

  const format = {
    ...typedFormat,
    type: 'image/png',
  } satisfies ImageFormat;

  return {
    format,
  };
};
```

Playground - https://tsplay.dev/N9Y1MN

Let me know if you have any other questions